# RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager row Height problem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I'm facing a problem with a `RecyclerView` with a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`. The issue is that i have a two columns span but I want some full span items in the middle of the recycler. Something like this:
[image: recycler with one full span cell]
The problem is that empty space between the full span cell and the upper one. Is there a method or something to tell the `ViewHolder` how to fill that space or something like that?

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you found any workaround?

Comment: I found a workaround but it's not very efficient. Basically I measure the two items before the full span one and assign to them the higher height to both. It works but it made the scroll a little bit rough.

Comment: I am also facing an issue with scroll.